# Delete statement in SQL file run in batch

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I use PHP to parse big CSV file and generate a SQL file that contains `INSERT` requests.
But at the beginning of the file, I also put a `DELETE` statement to clear the database before.

My file looks like something like this :

```
DELETE FROM `my_table` WHERE id IN (<list>) ;
INSERT INTO `my_table` .... (lot of values);
```

The lines are correctly inserted but the old ones are not deleted. I tried the delete request in PHPMyAdmin : it works. So the issue comes from the way I run the sql file.

I use the `exec` method in PHP :

```
$command = "mysql.exe -u user -pPassword my_database < sqlfile.sql";
```

It seems that this line, using the left chevron, works fine for INSERT statements, but not for DELETE ones.

Any idea to solve that ?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Any messages on console?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/896810/sql-batched-delete

Comment: No message ; @AvinashBabu : not the same problem exactly. My delete do work if I run it manually. The way I run the sql file is not the right one.

Comment: Ok don't ask me why but I works fine by adding `SET NAMES 'utf8';` at the beginning of the file....

Answer (score 0):

Code isn't entirely clear, but judging by your `WHERE ... IN` clause, you're either manually generating an ID via `SELECT` and manually incrementing (Usually bad), or you're simply doing it wrong. I see 2 options based on these scenarios:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE `my_table`
```

This empties all previous values from said table.

Second, if you were auto-generating ID's, set up the ID as auto-increment and try

```
# Null corresponds to auto-increment/primary key ID field in MySQL table
INSERT INTO `my_table` ... VALUES (null, value, value)
```

Comment: Finaly it works. I was doing "DELETE...; SET NAMES UTF-8; INSERT". I put the SET NAMES statement at the beginning and now it's ok?

Comment: Yes, that would break it since SET NAMES would need to be at the start of the script. But do you need SET NAMES? Are you sending special characters?